# Hovering over image and reveal div element

Tags: html, css

Is there any possible ways when I hover over one element and revealing my other element with pure css?
I know how to make simple hover effects such as

```
.class{
//some styles
}
.class:hover{
//some classes
}
```

But when I hover over other element and reveal another element?
(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: you need to post more code, what is the structure of the html? are they parents/children?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad no I only want to know hover over other element and reveal another element.. Is it possible with css only?

Comment: yes its possible but I think it depends on the relationship of the elements

Comment: @AbdulAhmad what do you mean by relationship of the elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px4jc5x0/)

If you have elements nested within each other, you can use the following:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'></div>
</div>

#parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
#child {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
#parent:hover #child {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of doing this. The elements have to be

1. adjacent
2. nested within (descendant)
3. nested within (Child)

So you could do as

**HTML**

```
<div class="test test1">hover over me</div>
<div class="test test1-h"></div>

<br><br>

<div class="test test2">
    hover over me
    <div class="test test2-h"></div>
</div>

<br><br>

 <div class="test test3">
     hover over me
     <div>
         <div class="test test3-h"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
    padding: 30px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.test .test {
    background: blue;
}
/******************Adjacent***************/
.test1:hover+div.test1-h {
    display: none;
}
/*****************nested within (descendant)***/    
.test2:hover > .test2-h {
    background: green;
}
/*****************nested within (Child)***/
.test3:hover .test3-h {
    background: tomato;
}
```

here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cx0wLyjh/1/)

Answer (score -2):

I also found onother solution for my code may be help fore someone else.
I achieved it with 
`opacity` and `visibility`
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn0szn6n/)