# Div ul list css menu

Tags: html, css, menu

How can I have a child div appear when I hover on the parent div? Please view`.`[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/king2525/gpzh153d/4/) My apologies if my code is incorrect.

Thank you

Comment: do you want the solution with just css or can use jquery/javascript?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gpzh153d/5/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hovering over image and reveal div element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712201/hovering-over-image-and-reveal-div-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#submenu11 {
width:550px;
height:400px;
float:none;
padding-left:1px;
padding-top:1px;
margin-right; 10px;
font:  15px/30px sans-serif;
clear: left;
margin-left: 181px;
border: 1px solid blue;
border-bottom: 5px solid blue;    
}
#left1, #right1 {
width: 35%; 
float:left;
margin-top: -85px;
}
#left1 {
margin-right: 1px;
border: 1px solid green;
box-sizing: inline-block;   
height: 100%;
}
#right1 {
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 60%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#abc_11 {
font:  15px/30px sans-serif;
height: 300px;
width:170px;
display: inline-block;
line-height:30px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
padding-right:10px;
border-right: 1px solid #0057A4;
clear:left;
}
submenulist ul li {
list-style-type: none;
clear: left;
margin-left: -40px ;    
}
a.menu1 {
font: 15px/30px sans-serif;
height: 30px;
width: 170px;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 30px;
background-color: white;
float: left;
padding-left:20px;
border-right: 1px solid blue;
margin-left: -10px;
clear:left;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
} 

a.submenulink1 {
border-right: 0px solid #E1E1E1;
border-top: 0px solid #444;
color: black;
display: block;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
font:  15px/30px sans-serif;
height: 30px;
}
a.submenulink1:hover {
background: lime;
color: white;  
}
.hide
{
display:none;
}
#abc_11:hover#abc_11 + #submenu11{
display:block;
} 


<div>
<div id="abc_11">
    <a class="menu1" href="#">GALAXY 11</a>
</div>    
<div id="submenu11" class="hide">
<div id="left1">
  <ul class="nav1">   
   <li class="submenulist"><a class="submenulink1" href="#">GALAXY S6 Edge</a></li>
   <li class="submenulist"><a class="submenulink1" href="#">GALAXY S6</a></li>
   <li class="submenulist"><a class="submenulink1" href="#">GALAXY S5</a></li>
   <li class="submenulist"><a class="submenulink1" href="#">GALAXY S4 Mini</a></li>
   <li class="submenulist"><a class="submenulink1" href="#">GALAXY S3 Mini VE</a></li>
  </ul>  
  </div>
  <div id="right1">
  <img src="http://www.samsung.com/uk/next/img/estore-recommend-    images/mobiles/S6edgegreen.jpg" alt=""></img>
  <a href="#">GALAXY S6 Edge information</a>
 </div>    
</div>  
</div>
```

I guess there is some issue with id being a number.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

you can go through this post, which specifies why the values which we can assign to id.
You also need to keep both the "abc_11" and "subMenu11" div inside a single div, as it is written that both the div must belong to the same parent.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Anirudh Modi. The issue was with ID being a number. I updated the IS with a letter.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have not mentioned jQuery as your tag but here is a solution which does the trick.

If you can use jQuery then I suggest you to use to achieve what you want because changing CSS property of one element when another element is hovered on is bit tricky and has many limitations,

[**Here is a simplified fiddle with jQuery**](https://jsfiddle.net/wucocnp2/)

This is the jQuery script that you can add in your file,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#a11").mouseover(function(){

         $("#submenu11").show();
     });
    $("#a11").mouseout(function(){

         $("#submenu11").hide();
     });
});
```

One more thing, it is not advisable to have id that starts with number, in your case `id="11"` might have issues in some browsers, that's why I have substituted `id=11` with `id="a11"`

If due to some reasons you don't want to use jQuery then I can give you an alternative approach using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, you may want to look into a readymade menu solution like this one:

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

The advantage is that you will get a crossbrowser compatible solution.